# php function db2_exec not running specific DB2 queries

Tags: php, sql, database, db2, delimiter

I'm trying to query a DB2 database via a php script.

```
   if ($conn) {
    $stmt = db2_prepare($conn, $sql);
   if ($stmt) {
      $success = db2_execute($stmt);
      if (!$success) {
         $result[]=  "exec errormsg1: " .db2_stmt_errormsg($stmt);
         echo implode(' ',$result);
         $message = implode(' ',$result); ?>
         <script>
         window.alert(' <?php echo $message; ?>');
         </script>
      <?php 
      }
      else
      {
        while ($row = db2_fetch_both($stmt)) 
        {
          if ($format == "human"){
                $result[] = implode("       ", $row);
            } else {
                $result[] = implode(",", $row);

            }
        }
```

I'm running into issues with certain queries being ran using either db2_exec or db2_execute.

I was having issues with the code above with meta data type queries though and found some workarounds , like for example if my sql was hardcoded to

```
$query = "describe table schemaID.tablename";
```

I would need to modify it by encasing it in

```
$sql = "call SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('".$query."')";
```

so while that works for the describe function I'm left scratching my head over what to do with these type of commands like

```
list tables for schema schemaID
```

which errors in

> exec errormsg1: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/AIX64] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "tables" was found following "list ".  Expected tokens may include:  "JOIN ".  SQLSTATE=42601

or

```
get db cfg
```

which errors in

> exec errormsg1: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/AIX64] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "db" was found following "GET".  Expected tokens may include:  "STMM".  SQLSTATE=42601

from the error messages I see it's having an issue with delimiters but I'm not sure exactly why since I can get other queries to work fine.

Also if I attempt to run those commands via the command line they'll both work fine without any issue.

Is there something I'm missing regarding how to correctly query DB2 in php ? Ideally I'd love to just be able to run the same queries exactly as I would from the command line and not face these issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute [DB2 SQL statements](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0011049.html) with that PHP code. What you are asking for is to also run [DB2 CLP commands](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc-gentopic3.html) within your code which is not possible by definition.

You could try to find solutions in the DB2 manual for some of the tasks, e.g., using the ADMIN_CMD stored procedure. For some commands like "LIST TABLES" there is a workaround by directly querying the [DB2 system catalog](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008443.html), e.g., the table SYSCAT.TABLES.

Comment: Thank you for that , I was unaware of the differences between SQL and CLP statements. For some reason I just assumed the db2_exec would mimic the db2 command line !